# static invocation of Class.getName()

Tags: java, spring, osgi

I stumbled upon the following code in `NestedRuntimeException` in `org.springframework.core`:

```
static {
    NestedExceptionUtils.class.getName();
}
```

What is the use of having such a block?

Comment: My guess is that this is a trick to force the JVM class loader to load the class `NestedExceptionUtils`.  But maybe there are other Spring specific reasons as well.

Comment: I was wondering why there would be no comment on a line like this, so I looked up the source. Of course there is a comment right before that statement that pretty much explains it, it's just not included in the question: "Eagerly load the NestedExceptionUtils class to avoid classloader deadlock issues on OSGi when calling getMessage(). Reported by Don Brown; SPR-5607"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It will `eagerly` load the `NestedExceptionUtils` class to avoid classloader deadlock. There was a bug reported ([SPR-5607](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5607)) "Non-trivial NestedRuntimeException.getMessage() can cause deadlocks on OSGi" and this is the solution for the same issue.

Edited:

It is mentioned also in the source code as a comment. For full source code docs please follow the [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-core/3.1.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/core/NestedRuntimeException.java). Here is the part of the source code of `NestedRuntimeException` class.

```
static {
    // Eagerly load the NestedExceptionUtils class to avoid classloader deadlock
    // issues on OSGi when calling getMessage(). Reported by Don Brown; SPR-5607.
    NestedExceptionUtils.class.getName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link!

Comment: They really should have added a comment with that reason.

Comment: @Bergi there is a comment right before the lines quoted in the question

Comment: @Bergi There is a comment in the source code with the reason. I have edited and added that details also. Thanks!!!